# Displaying content based on the field value

Tags: views

I have a view that displays my content of a specific content type that has a image field. I also have a check box field for that content type. My requirement is that i need the content that has the checkbox checked to be displayed at the top of the list in the view. Could someone tell me how to achieve it?

Comment: You could add a descending sort by for that field. Or create a views attachment that's filtered to only show items with that checkbox checked and then attach it to the top of your main display

Answer (score 1):

Under `Sort criteria` add your check-box field and set it to `Sort ascending` (it may be descending in your case depending on your field values).

Then if you have more than one Sort criteria **Rearrange** them so that the checkbox field comes first, on top. This way the results are first sorted by the check-box field value.

This works independently of the image field. Is your image field tied to the check-box somehow?